# Execute function depending on multiple ajax calls status

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make 3 AJAX calls simultaneously if all of them succeed then I need to execute a function. If any call fails I need to know which one it is and what error it threw.

I think jquery promise is what I need. I have looked into many examples doing `when` & `then` on promises but haven't seen any tacking this particular issue.

I'll appreciate id someone can guide me to right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little verbose to make a point, but you stick the returned deferred from the ajax call in an array, and then use `$.when` on that array to do something when they are all done:

```
var request1 = $.ajax({
    url: 'someurl1.php'
}).fail(function() {
    alert('request 1 failed');
});

var request2 = $.ajax({
    url: 'someurl2.php'
}).fail(function() {
    alert('request 2 failed');
});

var request3 = $.ajax({
    url: 'someurl3.php'
}).fail(function() {
    alert('request 3 failed');
});

$.when.apply($, [request1, request2, request3]).then(function() {
    // all done
});
```

note that if any of the calls fail, `.then()` will not be called

Comment: Great, Is there any more elegant way to make these 3 ajax calls. It looks like lots of duplicate code?

Comment: @RuntimeException - Sure, there are probably hundreds of ways to do this, here's one [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEUDR/)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

- Declare 3 status variables
- make the 3 AJAX calls
- set the status variables in the AJAX call callback functions
- have each callback function call you final function as its last instruction
- write your final function by first checking the state of the status variables (undefined?) and when all 3 are defined, execute your code